# Get IPv4 and IPv6 address using NsdServiceInfo?

Tags: java, android, nsd

I used NSDServiceInfo.getHost (). getHostAddress () output is the IPv4 to IPv6 device and router. for the device, I can already IPV4 so I need IPv6. as well as to the router, I can already so I need IPV4 IPV6.

The solution I have tried. but when his hostaddress issued IPV4, then exit the error "Not an IPv6 address: [xx, xx, xx, xx]

Meanwhile, when it issued hostaddress IPv6, then the error message "java.net.Inet6Address can not be cast to java.net.Inet4Address"

I like this coding

```
List <NSDServiceInfo> Data = new ArrayList<>();
InetAddress hostInet =InetAddress.getByName(Data.get(position).getHost().GetHostAddress());
byte [] addressBytes = hostInet.getAddress();

Inet6Address dest6 = Inet6Address.getByAddress(Data.get(position).getHost().GetHostAddress(), addressBytes, NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(hostInet));
Inet4Address dest4 = (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByAddress (Data.get(position).getHost().GetHostAddress(), addressBytes);
Log.d ( "IP", "IPv4" + dest4.getHostAddress ());
Log.d ( "IP", "IPv6:" + dest6.getHostAddress ());
```

Answer (score 2):

First fetch the `InetAddress` object using static function by giving host name

```
InetAddress hostInet= InetAddress.getByName(hostNameString);
```

Now we need the byte array representation using  `hostInet`

```
byte [] addressBytes = hostInet.getAddress();
```

Now you can use this `addressBytes` to format is as IPv4 or IPv6 using `Inet6Address` or `Inet4Address` with [getByAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html#getByAddress(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20java.net.NetworkInterface)) plus you need to pass hostName , bytes address and network interface using [getByInetAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getByInetAddress(java.net.InetAddress))  function

```
Inet6Address dest = Inet6Address.getByAddress(hostNameString, addressBytes, NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(hostInet));
```

or

```
Inet4Address dest = Inet4Address.getByAddress(hostNameString, addressBytes, NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(hostInet));
```

Now you can retrieve either text or byte representation of `dest` object using [getAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html#getAddress()) or [getHostAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html#getHostAddress()) functions

Comment: thanks for the solution. I have tried. sorry, I've posted my answer. I asked for his help again. thank you

Answer (score 1):

this my fault for not complete in asking. so I used NSDServiceInfo.getHost (). getHostAddress () output is the IPv4 to IPv6 device and router. for the device, I can already IPV4 so I need IPv6. as well as to the router, I can already so I need IPV4 IPV6.

The solution I have tried. but when his hostaddress issued IPV4, then exit the error "Not an IPv6 address: [xx, xx, xx, xx]

Meanwhile, when it issued hostaddress IPv6, then the error message "java.net.Inet6Address can not be cast to java.net.Inet4Address"

I like this coding

```
List <NSDServiceInfo> Data = new ArrayList<>();
InetAddress hostInet =InetAddress.getByName(Data.get(position).getHost().GetHostAddress());
byte [] addressBytes = hostInet.getAddress();

Inet6Address dest6 = Inet6Address.getByAddress(Data.get(position).getHost().GetHostAddress(), addressBytes, NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(hostInet));
Inet4Address dest4 = (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByAddress (Data.get(position).getHost().GetHostAddress(), addressBytes);
Log.d ( "IP", "IPv4" + dest4.getHostAddress ());
Log.d ( "IP", "IPv6:" + dest6.getHostAddress ());
```

sorry if my English is bad
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Class `NsdServiceInfo` has a method `getHostAddress()` that is a type of [java.net.InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html). And the textual representation of an IP address is address family specific:

- for IPv4 address format, please refer to [Inet4Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet4Address.html);
- for IPv6 address format, please refer to [Inet6Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address.html).

Both these classes extend `InetAddress`. You need a method `public String getHostAddress()` that returns the IP address string in textual presentation.

Comment: thanks for the solution. sorry can be more specific to make his new method? thank you